# on_member_join function not working in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm working on a bot and the on_member_join function isn't working when a user joins the server. My function is in a cog and is the only function that won't work,

```
def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):

@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        print('working')
```

Comment: Did you enable `intents.members`? Also please fix the indentation

Comment: Do you have another `on_member_join` event defined? Whether it's in your main program file or it's in a cog, there should only be one `on_member_join` event defined.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the indentation is just wrong while pasting here and not in the actual code.
If you haven't done this already, the new version of discord.py has something called intents. First you have to go to the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) and activate it. Then you have to add the intents to your code.
This will enable all the Intents:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-', intents=intents)
```

Comment: Yeah, I had it in my code but forgot to check it off in the developer portal. And the indentation was only like that when I pasted it. That fixed it, thanks so much.